# Swift3 changes to UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift3, xcode8, unsafemutablepointer

I am porting one of my iOS Apps to Swift3 / Xcode8. 
I have embedded a C library, which expects a function parameter of type:

```
char ***
```

In Swift2.3 this was translated into a:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>
```

So i could declare that pointer in my swift code like that:

```
let myPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>.alloc(1)
```

This worked well until i updated to Xcode8 with Swift3, now i am getting a compiler error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?>!'
```

Can i anybody help me to understand the changes in swift3? What does this Optional, Optional, Implicit Unwrapped Optional (?) mean in this context and how i can i declare a pointer with this type?

Comment: But I didn't get any error ```let _ = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>.allocate(capacity: 1)```

Comment: @AlvinVarghese I am getting the error when i pass it as a param to my C function which expects an `char ***` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let myPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<
    UnsafeMutablePointer<
    UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
```

Alternatively you could also use the `_Nonnull` annotation to keep the pointer as non-optional.  Suppose the C function is `void setPtr(char ***)`. You could write its declaration available to Swift via a bridging header as follows:

```
void setPtr(char * _Nonnull * _Nonnull * _Nonnull);
```

Then in your Swift code you can do something like this:

```
let myPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<
        UnsafeMutablePointer<
        UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>.allocate(capacity: 1)
setPtr(myPointer)
let myInt = myPointer.pointee.pointee.pointee
```

But what if `setPtr(char *** ptr)` in C code, where `_Nonnull` is not usable, does something like

```
*ptr = NULL;
```

? Then the Swift code will crash at runtime.  However, using optionals you don't need the `_Nonnull` annotation in the declaration of `setPtr()`, your Swift code becomes

```
let myPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<
        UnsafeMutablePointer<
        UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
setPtr(myPointer)
let myInt = myPointer.pointee?.pointee?.pointee
```

and it won't crash at runtime.
Thus the approach with optionals, enforced by Swift3 when you don't use `_Nonnull`, is safer.

Comment: Thank you very much